# How to fix "The item can't be moved to the Trash because it can't be deleted" error

Tags: error, trash

Got this error:

`The item XYZ can't be moved to the Trash because it can't be deleted.`

Never seen this before. How to I enable it to be deleted?

[image]

File is stored on an SD card.

Checked permissions. Says:
`You can only read`

Which I have also never seen.

Tried `touch /Volumes/<Name of SD Card>` and got the response: `touch: /Volumes/<Name of SD Card>: Read-only file system`

[image]

Comment: what format is the sd card?

Comment: Is the SD card write protected?  Test it out by issuing the command `touch /Volumes/<Name of SD Card>`  Let us know what happens

Comment: @Sam format is ExFAT

Comment: @Allan response ```touch: /Volumes/1: Read-only file system``` Which is weird because it is ExFAT which I thought was Read Write.

Comment: Back up the SD card (copy contents to a folder on your Desktop) then wipe the SD card.  If you can't then the issue is the SD card.

Comment: @Allan Will try that. Copying the SD card to a HD now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue. The Lock Switch was set to Lock.

A client had sent me the SD card with video files. I didn't even think to check the lock switch when I loaded it up.

So flipping that to unlock, and it fixed the error and the permissions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unlock permissions, change your permissions to read/write.
If you can't do this, then that means that it's a format that macOS can only read, and not write to.

Comment: The format doesn't determine if you can read or write.  Write protection and file permissions do that.

Comment: I can't seem to access the permissions to unlock it. Tried Get Info, all the usual methods.

Comment: Are you admin?.

Comment: @Allan macOS doesn't come with read/right abilities for all formats

Comment: Can you run diskutil info?

Comment: @Sam I am admin. Seems like ExFAT sometimes has read write issues - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8550450

Comment: @Sam First Aid failed to mount the volume. But I figured out what was wrong. The lock switch was set. sigh...

Comment: Don't worry about it, we all make mistakes sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these things without success (the lock switch was not on, but my permissions also said "You can only read"). BUT when I switched ON the lock switch on my SD card, launched it, ejected it, THEN turned the lock switch off and launched it again, everything worked as it did before and I could erase files. I had also never gotten this alert before. Weird glitchy stuff. I use a 2014 iMac, Mojave 10.14.6.